# How to have multiple instances of getInitialState in Reactjs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

This is my code in React. I have multiple instances of `getInitialState` for different functions. However, I am finding that there may be a problem with getting them all to run this way.

```
getInitialState: function(){
if (localStorage.getItem('something'))
{return {signedin: true}}
else {return {signedin: false}}
},

getInitialState:function(){
return {error: true}
},

getInitialState:function(){
return {fliphouse: false}
},
```

To explain, the second instance of `getInitialState`, as is, does not work. That is, unless, I flip the order of the second and third `getInitialState`. When I do that, the code runs as it should. But I get the feeling React is trying to tell me something.

Is this normally the way to organize React code within a component?

Comment: because in JS everything is an object, you can't have an object with two (or more) identical keys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can define them all in the same object:

```
getInitialState() {
  return {
    signedIn: !!localStorage.getItem('something'),
    error: false,
    fliphouse: false
  };
}
```

You can change them individually anywhere in the component (except in the render() function), e.g.:

```
this.setState({ error: true }) // causes a new render
```

Answer (score 1):

This is not the correct way to put the initial state of the component. Initial state function is called only once when you component is about to mount; over here you set the state of the component(what variables or object properties you need) and then update them accordingly using setState in other methods like componentDidMount etc..

So in your question I would say put all 3 variables signedIn, error and fliphouse in the state object and then update this object. So a single initialState function would do.